# Fast algorithm for RGB <--> HSL conversion

Tags: graphics, colors, color-space

I'm looking for fast algorithms (typically using integers only) for converting RGB data to HSL data and then converting back to RGB data.
I've found algorithms (wikipedia) for these conversions but they are not fast as they requiere floating operations.

Does anyone know efficient algorithms that use integers only ?

Comment: Have you actually tried writing, running, and benchmarking this supposedly "slow" code?

Comment: If you want to preserve accuracy, you will still have to represent the values as floats while doing the conversion: [Wikipedia conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSL)

Comment: Have you considered a different color space that's easier to convert to/from and gives you the same advantages as HLS space? Converting to/from Y'CbCr is a matrix multiply and there are lots of code examples for it on the web that are integer only.

Comment: To Matt Ball : Yes I have wrote the code and I did run it. It's slow as I need to do it for a large number of pixels.

Comment: To Blender : if you mean by accuracy the fact that when doing RGB->HSL and then HSL->RGB I should retrieve the same initial data, then I don't mind about accuracy as long as it remains near values.

Comment: To user1118321 : Thanks but I need to work with HSL.

Comment: You could speed up your current code by doing any or all of the following: 1)use SIMD instructions (SSE, AltiVec, whatever), 2)process multiple parts of the image at the same time on multiple threads/cores, or 3)do the processing on the GPU.

Comment: You want to use integers? You should then specify the range for each component of both representations.

Answer (score 2):

Almost 5 years and no answer? Well, here's 50%: HSL -> RGB

```
uint32_t hsl2rgb(uint8_t h, uint8_t s, uint8_t l) {
    uint8_t  r, g, b, lo, c, x, m;
    uint16_t h1, l1, H;
    l1 = l + 1;
    if (l < 128) {
        c = ((l1<<1) * s) >> 8;
    }
    else {
        c = (512 - (l1<<1)) * s >> 8;
    }

    H = h*6; // 0 to 1535 (actually 1530)
    lo = H & 255;          // Low byte  = primary/secondary color mix
    h1 = lo + 1;
    if ((H & 256) == 0) { // even sextant, like red to yellow
        x = h1 * c >> 8;
    }
    else { // odd sextant, like yellow to green
        x = (256 - h1) * c >> 8;
    }
    m = l - (c >> 1);
    switch(H >> 8) {       // High byte = sextant of colorwheel
        case 0 : r = c  ; g = x  ; b = 0  ; break; // R to Y
        case 1 : r = x  ; g = c  ; b = 0  ; break; // Y to G
        case 2 : r = 0  ; g = c  ; b = x  ; break; // G to C
        case 3 : r = 0  ; g = x  ; b = c  ; break; // C to B
        case 4 : r = x  ; g = 0  ; b = c  ; break; // B to M
        default: r = c  ; g = 0  ; b = x  ; break; // M to R
    }

    return r+m<<16 | g+m<<8 | b+m;
}
```